# Why doesn't me flask app redirect the user?

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a flask blog. After the registration form is completed, I want to redirect the user back to the home page and show the user a message.

The problem is that the user doesn't get redirected. It only flashes once.

Python code:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

HTML code:

```html
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
      {% for category, message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ message }}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
```

Comment: did you checked `print( form.validate_on_submit() )` ? What do you have in `RegistrationForm` ? Maybe your data are not valid. Where is function `home` ? Maybe it displays the same HTML file.